# Can I do a number of string replace in one statement in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to few junk characters in my string using the following statement:

```
desc = string.replace(desc,'&ldquo;','"')
desc = string.replace(desc,'&rdquo;','"')
desc = string.replace(desc,'&middot;','.')
```

Can I write the above 3 statements in to a single statement or atlease the 1st two statements to a single statement.

I can not use any third-party libraries in my project.

**Edit @unutbu:**
My String looks like below:

> This is `'&ldquo;' my teststring '&rdquo;'.` I want to replace unicode with appropriate HTML not the whole string only with unicode values.

After using the code:

```
import HTMLParser

text='&ldquo; &rdquo; &middot;'
parser=HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
desc=parser.unescape(text)
```

I am getting only the HTML equivalents , not the string. But I just want to replace the appropriate values keeping everything in Original String.

I expect the out put as below:

> This is "my teststring". I want to replace unicode with appropriate HTML not the whole string only with unicode values.

Comment: Does "I can not use any third-party libraries in my project." mean this is homework? If so please flag it as such.

Comment: @Duncan3, I am using python for developing Plex plugin n this is going to run on embeded system. Thatz Y I can't use third partie library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser) is in the standard library:

```
import HTMLParser

text='&ldquo; &rdquo; &middot;'
parser=HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
desc=parser.unescape(text)
print(desc)
# “ ” ·
```

If you want that in a single statement, you could of course do

```
desc=HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(text)
```

but that might not be an advantage if you need to call `unescape` in more than one place, and in general, chaining calls like this makes it harder to identify where exceptions occur.

Note that `HTMLParser.unescape` will unescape *all* HTML entities defined in `htmlentitydefs.names2codepoint` (plus `&apos;`).

---

Edit: HTMLParser.unescape returns different characters than what you posted.
To get exactly those characters, you might use [xml.sax.saxutils](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html):

```
text='&ldquo; &rdquo; &middot;'
import xml.sax.saxutils as saxutils
print(saxutils.unescape(text,{'&ldquo;':'"', '&rdquo;':'"', '&middot;':'.', }))
# " " .
```

Note that `saxutils.unescape` also replaces `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`. If you wish to replace only `&ldquo;`, `&rdquo;`, and `&middot`, then I'd use [aix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428259/can-i-do-a-number-of-string-replace-in-one-statement-in-python/7428300#7428300).

Comment: Nice as this is, it's worth pointing out that it returns different characters to those given in the OP's code.

Comment: @unutbu, By using it the complete string get replaced by HTML chars. Edited the question

Comment: @Subhen: Try changing `text='&ldquo; &rdquo; &middot;'` to `text="This is &ldquo; my teststring &rdquo;. I want to replace..."`

Comment: @subhen: Are there single quotes around `'&ldquo;'`? If so, you'll end up with `'“'`.

Comment: @unutbu, No . I just posted in the question

Comment: @Subhen: Or use `desc=parser.unescape(desc)` to replace `desc` with its unescaped version, rather than `desc=parser.unescape(text)`

Comment: @untbu, Yes , Did desc=parser.unescape(desc) . That's working gr8. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first two you can do together using regular expressions:

```
desc = re.sub('&[rl]dquo;', '"', desc)
```

If you foresee having many such patterns, you could put them into a dictionary and apply in a loop:

```
patterns = {'&[rl]dquo;': '"',
            '&middot;':   '.'}

for pattern, repl in patterns.items():
    desc = re.sub(pattern, repl, desc)
```

Like your original code, this doesn't scale well for longer `desc` since it scans the string multiple times. Here's an extensible version that scans the string just once:

```
import re

subs = {'rdquo':  '"',
        'ldquo':  '"',
        'middot': '.'}

def repl(matchobj):
  return subs.get(matchobj.group(1), matchobj.group(0))

desc = 'sdf sdfs &ldquo; sdf sd &ldquo; skdfh &middot; sdf &nonsub; jk'
print re.sub('&(.*?);', repl, desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Python 3.4 we can now do

```
import html
text='&ldquo; &rdquo; &middot;'
desc=html.unescape(text)
print(desc)  # “ ” ·
```