# How to remove space between $ and numbers in python

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am having a bit of trouble with an assignment in python. This is my first assignment so please go easy on me.

I have this line:

```
print('You can save a total of $',saved,'over',number_of_weeks,'weeks.')
```

The output is:

> You can save a total of $ 5200 over 52 weeks.

How do I go about removing the space between the $ and 5200.

Please remember this is for an assignment, so a general answer would help me more than a specific answer (Please give me a hint, not the complete answer). This will help me to learn by myself. I just don't know where to start the problem solving process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I do a number of string replace in one statement in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428259/can-i-do-a-number-of-string-replace-in-one-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current version, you let `print` handle multiple strings. That means that whatever is between them is managed by print.

What you need to do is turn those multiple strings into a single one that is formatted the way you like it.

You have multiple options here, either string concatenation (`"abc" + "DEF"`) or [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Good luck on your journey into programming!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```
In [1]: saved = 42
In [2]: number_of_weeks = 3.14159
In [3]: print('You can save a total of ${} over {} weeks.'.format(saved, number_of_weeks))
You can save a total of $42 over 3.14159 weeks.
```

It is also supports named arguments to make your code more readable:

```
In [5]: print('You can save a total of ${saved} over {weeks} weeks.'.format(saved=saved, weeks=number_of_weeks))
You can save a total of $42 over 3.14159 weeks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the type of saved variable to string and add a concatenation operator `+` before that.

```
print('You can save a total of $'+str(saved),'over',number_of_weeks,'weeks.')
```

**Example:**

```
>>> saved = 123
>>> nu = 4
>>> print('You can save a total of $'+str(saved),'over',nu,'weeks.')
You can save a total of $123 over 4 weeks.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use like C language.

```
print('You can save a total of $%d' %saved + ' over %d' %number_of_weeks + 'weeks.')
```

Comment: First, you need not break the strint into multiple when you already use format string syntax (instead leave ultiple %d's and then format with a tuple) and secondly the `%` syntax is deprecated in python 3 and is to be removed in the (near) future.